# Tensorflow-gpu not utilizing gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create and train a CNN model. But every time I run the code, the tensorflow is not utilising GPU instead it uses CPU. I have installed the latest version of tensorflow. Attaching the details below.

```
python => 3.9.5\
Tensorflow-GPU => 2.5.0\
CUDA => 11.3\
cuDNN => 8.2.1
```

While running I get the following output with a warning message. (Platform: VS code)

> 2021-07-28 15:35:13.163991: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:337] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.

[System Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w11Eg.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EAMv.png)

Code is accessible [here](https://github.com/kv-95/LULC-Classification)

Note: I had already tried adding the following code to activate gpu and it isn't working.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')
```

[Output for suggestion:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgrPl.png)

Comment: There no need to use `tensorflow-gpu`. You can use `pip install tensorflow` and it will use the gpu.

Comment: I had previously tried that. But it wasn't using the GPU. So i reinstalled with ```tensorflow-gpu```

Comment: Now you see this was not the issue.

Comment: Can you please suggest some way by which I could utilize the GPU. Right now the GPU is used only below 10%. Since I am not getting any errors, I believe that it doesn't have to do anything with versions of CUDA or CuDNN.

Comment: You are getting a warning though (last warning in the output). I recommend you copy it and add it here so people will see it in the question itself.

Comment: Sure will do that. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs:", len(physical_devices))
```

Since your model is quite small it is possible that the GPU is so bottlenecked by the rest of your system that it can't use the full GPU.

On another note, Task Manager is not the best tool to check on the GPU load, if available use nvidia-smi.

Comment: I tried the above code and I am attaching the output above.

Comment: @AnonymousAnalyst that output looks to me like its working properly

Comment: you can try wrapping your model and training in `with tf.device('/device:gpu:0'):` that should be done automatically but who knows

Comment: I think it's working now. nvidia-smi shows gpu usage. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AnonymousAnalyst was it the `with tf.device`?

Comment: it was working even without ```with tf.device```. The task manager graph was showing wrong values. nvidia-smi showed the exact value of gpu usage while running the ML tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically do what the warning says I set it as env setting as follows

```
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION'] = 'false'
```

Comment: Thera are somethings you can do to improve performance in production, also as os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The GPU was being utilized, it's just that the task manager was not showing it properly.